# 405 (METHOD NOT ALLOWED) javascript y flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, fetch

Lo que quuiero es una api del valor de un input range con backend de flask y un esp32 pero esas
si las tengo bien pero lo que me falla mucho es el javascript.
La url es el servidor que me da flask

Esta es la parte del javascript

```
var inputRange = document.getElementById("rango");

inputRange.addEventListener("input", function() {
    const valor = inputRange.value;

  // Hacer una petición HTTP POST a la API
  fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ valor: valor })
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => console.error(error));

});
```

La parte de flask solo es esto

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def inicio():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

y la parte del HTML

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="180" value="90" id="rango" name="rango">
        <div id="valorRango">
        </div>
```

Comment: A ver si entiendo: cada vez que estás modificando el valor en tu input, ¿estás queriendo hacer una petición? Además ese route en flask lo único que hace es renderizar el index.html...

Comment: Sip porque ese valor lo necesito que lo obtenga un esp32, perdón pero soy muy malo para el frontend

Answer (score 3):

El método [`route()`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/api/?highlight=route#flask.Flask.route) por default soporta el *método* GET, según indica la documentación.

> The methods parameter defaults to [**"GET"**]. HEAD and OPTIONS are added automatically.

(El resaltado es mío)

Si quieres soportar el _método? POST, debes indicarlo explícitamente, por ejemplo:

```
@app.route("/", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
```